Google Distroless Image with Apache Tomcat - Java 11 - Errors out
I'm trying to use Distroless as my base image and copy the apache tomcat application server package to the docker image and did all the necessary steps to create a docker image
which will deploy the war file to the tomcat webapps directory and start the tomcat server by using the following command
CMD ["java","-cp","/usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar",org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap","start"]
I was successful in building the docker image, but when I ran the built image, I see an error saying "Error: Unable to access jarfile java".
With this error, I even tried changing the permission on the bootstrap.jar and copied the same to the apache tomcat bin directory in the DockerFile. After that
tried building and running the updated docker image, i got the same error as before.
Here is the DockerFile which I have tried
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java:11
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
ADD apache-tomcat-9.0.87.tar.gz /usr/local/tomcat
COPY --chown=nonroot:nonroot bootstrap.jar /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
COPY app1.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR=9 \
    TOMCAT_VERSION=9.0.87 \
    CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat \   
    JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1G -Xmx1G"
    
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java","-cp","/usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar",org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap","start"]

Does anyone faced this issue before ?  Appreciate any suggestion on this issue.

Not a Java developer but your approach has some issues: (1) you're using distroless/java:11 which isn't being updated (2) You copy apache-tomcat-9.0.87.tar.gz but don't untar it; (3) distroless don't include a shell so you can't untar the file in this image; (4) the entrypoint is java so you can't use CMD ["java",...] see docs

@DazWilkin Thanks for your suggestion. It helped me move further on this.
